# Sizing does not apply to images using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Sizing property of bootstrap does not apply to the images. If I try to style them inline, everything works as planned, but whenever I try to set it as h-100, the rule does not apply to the images anymore. Can somebody please explain why h-100 is not working?

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="img/hero-bg_1.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <h1> Denim Jackets </h1>
    </div>


    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/hero-bg_2.jpg" alt="Second slide" style="height: 100vh">
      <h1> text on the second page </h1>
    </div>


    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/hero-bg_3.jpg" alt="Third slide" style="height: 100vh">
      <h1> text on the third page </h1>
    </div>

  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: Sure, here it is! https://jsfiddle.net/uymn93of/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you are applying `h-100` only to the image of `active` carousel. It didn't get applied because your parent element don't have a fixed height. Set a `height` to `active` class and check.

`.active{
    height:100vh;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry in that case you can't apply width or height directly to the image tag.
Use the structure in the following way.

```
 <div class="h-25 d-inline-block" style="width: 120px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1)"> <img class="rounded mx-auto
d-block" src="img/hero-bg_2.jpg" alt="Second slide" style="height:
 100vh"></div
```